# Redis is outputting true instead of the desired value

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, redis

I have nodejs running and I want to call this function:

```
function name(id) {
  var x = rclient.get(id, function(err, reply) {
    return reply;
  });
  return x;
}
```

however when I try to get the output of the function with `console.log(name(1))` the output is `true`, instead of the value stored on the redis server. this seems like a simple thing to fix, however, it has me stumped.

Comment: `What are "err" and "reply"?`

Comment: "err" is only used if the server has an error and "reply" is the servers response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're using callbacks so the `return` value inside your callback function won't be returned to `x`.

Try this (depending on your redis client, I've assumed you use `node-redis`):

```
function name(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rclient.get(id, function (err, reply) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      resolve(reply);
    });
  });
}

// call with
name(1).then((value) => console.log(value)).catch((err) => console.log(err));

// better yet (inside async function)
async main() {
  const value = await name(1);
}
```

Or, do yourself a favour and use `handy-redis` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/handy-redis):

```
async function name(id) {
  return rclient.get(id);
}

// call with the same as above
```

Essentially, you're getting slightly confused with async/sync calls. The fact `x` resolves to `true` is likely the implementation of the `.get` method, and **not** the callback.

> instead of the value stored on the redis server. this seems like a simple thing to fix, however, it has me stumped.

I felt like you when I first started with Node.js, it's odd compared to most languages, however, you'll soon find it more natural (especially with async/await syntax)